# Cannot close <dialog> element with display set to grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog

The [HtmlDialogElement.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/close) function seems to have no effect on a `<dialog>` element when that dialog has its `display` style set to `grid`.

Does anyone happen to know why? Note that removing the `display: grid` allow the dialog to function correctly. I have seen this behavior on the latest versions of both Chrome and Firefox.

See minimum reproduction below. If you prefer, here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/ChristianMay/pen/MWrmdzJ

```js
let dialog = document.querySelector('dialog')
let closeButton = document.querySelector("#dialog-close");
closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.close();
})
```

```css
dialog {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<dialog class="dialog" open="">
  Test
</dialog>

<button id="dialog-close">Close dialog</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dialog is considered to be open (or shown) if the attribute `open` is present.

Once this attribute is not present, the dialog is hidden. I suppose that setting the display to grid overrides the default styling for dialog, which should hide the dialog whenever `open` is removed. We could restore this behavior by adding styling to the dialog without `open` attribute.

```js
let dialog = document.querySelector('dialog')
let closeButton = document.querySelector("#dialog-close");
closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   dialog.close();
})
```

```css
dialog:not([open]){
  display:none;
}


dialog{
  display:grid;
}
```

```html
<dialog class="dialog" open="">
  Test
</dialog>

<button id="dialog-close">Close dialog</button>
```

Comment: It looks like that's the case - if you inspect the dialog after it fails to close (once the "open" attribute is gone), it looks like both Firefox and Chrome show the following style as applying from the user agent stylesheet:

`dialog:not([open]) { display: none; }`

Since that style comes from the User Agent stylesheet, it has very low specificity, and will be overwritten if you ever set the display property to any value - not just grid.

I kind of expected the dialog closing to work a little bit differently than slapping `display: none` on there, but I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

*Already answered* , but you could also display `<dialog>` as a grid only if it is an *opened* dialog ;)

```
dialog[open] {
  display: grid;
}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors
>
> The CSS **attribute selector** matches elements based on the presence or value of a given attribute.

Demo snippet using the CSS attribute selector

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog')

let closeButton = document.querySelector("#dialog-close");
closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.removeAttribute("open");
})

let openButton = document.querySelector("#dialog-open");
openButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dialog.setAttribute("open", "");
})
```

```css
dialog[open] {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<dialog class="dialog" open="">
  Test
</dialog>

<button id="dialog-close">Close dialog</button>
<button id="dialog-open">Open dialog</button>
```

[fork of your pen](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWVgNXK)

Comment: You're absolutely right! An even more elegant solution.